# Cumulative product in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write an algorithm to give me the cumulative product such `A=[1, 3, 5, 6, 8]`, `cumprodA = [1, 3, 15, 90, 720]`. I don't think its too hard for an experienced statistician but my programming skills are kind of weak.

Comment: `list(itertools.accumulate(x, operator.mul))`

Comment: You should be able to adapt this from your ability to write a cumulative sum.  Let's see the code, even if it's a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us where it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cumulative product of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41784149/cumulative-product-of-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with your multiplicative identity (`1`), and multiply it by each number, remembering the result and appending to a cumprod list while you do so.

```
def cumprod(lst):
    results = []
    cur = 1
    for n in lst:
        cur *= n
        results.append(cur)
    return results
```

Note that this is the general solution for any Monoidal operation. Start with the `mzero` and do the same steps. Cumulative sum starts with `0`, Cumulative list extends starts with `[]`, etc.

Comment: This is also a fun example of the terseness of Haskell. In Haskell `cumprod` is defined as `cumprod = drop 1 . scanl (*) 0`

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.accumulate`

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> A=[1, 3, 5, 6, 8]
>>> list(accumulate(A, lambda x,y: x*y))
[1, 3, 15, 90, 720]
```

Comment: that lambda is `operator.mul`

Comment: Bryan, I am speculating the reason you got a -4 I'd due to the idea that you didn't your example the old college try. Next time put up your idea worked out a bit and ppl won't think they are doing yr homework. Lol

Comment: Yes, but that is using a built in function. I have to write the algorithm, something like the way Adam did. Thanks though Sunitha.

Comment: oaxacamatt, nor sure what you are talking about but I am asking help for a general idea, my homework question has many more steps.