# Multiply the first element of a list by a given number and calculate a cumulative product of the resulting list

Tags: python, list, accumulate

I have the following list:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I want to multiply the first element by `9`, `(1*9)=9` and then all successive items by the result of the previous multiplication. See the following output:

```
[9, 18, 54, 216, 1080, 6480]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cumulative product of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41784149/cumulative-product-of-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could update the first item in the list, and use  [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) with [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html) to take the cumulative product of its values:

```
from operator import mul
from itertools import accumulate

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

l[0]*=9
list(accumulate(l, mul))
# [9, 18, 54, 216, 1080, 6480]
```